# Increase line width of border in legend

Tags: r, plot, legend

I have several boxes in a legend and would like to increase the line thickness of some of them to match the line thickness in the plot.

R code for blank

```
 plot( 1, type = 'n')
```

R code for legend - using `lwd` does not change line thickness for boxes

```
legend("topright",
       legend = c("2005 CA II Stations", "2005 Survey Domain",
                  "CA II Access Area","CA II Groundfish Closed Area",
                  "Trawl Strata","SAMS Areas","Statistical Areas"),
       bg = "white", pt.cex = c(2, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
       cex = 1, bty = "n", 
       pch = c(19, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
       col = c("red", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
       fill = c(NA, "gray", "gray", "white", "white", "white", "white"),
       lwd = c(NA, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1),
       border = c(NA, "black", "black", "black", "gray", "red", "blue"),
       x.intersp = 0.5, seg.len = 0.8, y.intersp = 1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `pch` which takes a `lwd` argument, e.g. `pch = 22`, filled square. Use `pt.lwd` if you want to set line width of points independently from that of any lines in the legend.

```
plot(1, type = 'n')
legend("topright", legend = c("2005 CA II Stations", "2005 Survey Domain",
                              "CA II Access Area", "CA II Groundfish Closed Area",
                              "Trawl Strata", "SAMS Areas", "Statistical Areas"),
       bty = "n",
       lty = 0,
       pch = c(19, rep(22, 6)),
       pt.cex = 2,
       pt.bg = c(NA, "gray", "gray", "white", "white", "white", "white"),
       pt.lwd = c(NA, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1),
       col = c("red", "black", "black", "black", "gray", "red", "blue"))
```

[image]

Comment: I just got back from vacation and will check it on Monday.  Thanks for the response.